# Windows Form Foreach remove only removes half Form.Control elements

Tags: windows, powershell, forms, winforms

Why doesn't it remove both/all elements?

Code:

```
    $AAD = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $AAD.Name = 'AAD'
    $AAD.text = 'AAD'
    $AAD.Checked = $true 
    $AAD.AutoSize = $true
    $AAD.width = 47
    $AAD.height = 30
    $AAD.enabled = $true
    $AAD.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12, 76)
    $AAD.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif', 10)

    $AD = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $AD.Name = 'AD'
    $AD.text = 'AD'
    $AD.Checked = $true 
    $AD.AutoSize = $true
    $AD.width = 45
    $AD.height = 20
    $AD.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(64, 76)
    $AD.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif', 10)

    $array = @('AAD', 'AD')
    $Form.Controls | where { $array -contains $_.Name } | foreach { $Form.Controls.RemoveByKey($_.Name) }
```

If i log the name of which elements it finds it logs this (So it does find both, but doesn't remove them both):

```
AAD
AD
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't explain why it's failing to remove one of the controls but I can provide you a more robust way of doing it that will not have such issue using `.Remove` instead of `.RemoveByKey`:

```
$form.Controls.AddRange(@($AD; $AAD))
'AAD', 'AD' | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($control in $Form.Controls.Find($_, $true)) {
        $form.Controls.Remove($control)
    }
}
$form.Controls.Count # 0
```

---

Following up on [Jimi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) helpful comment:

> The reason why half of the Controls remain is that removing elements in a `foreach` loop modifies the collection you're iterating over. A backwards for loop is one of the common counter-measures -- In general, you should dispose of the Controls that are not need anymore instead of removing them. `Controls.Remove()` doesn't dispose anything (this behavior is somewhat different in .NET 5+, though).

Modifying the collection while iterating it can explain OP's issue and the solution being a reverse `for` loop also works to solve the problem. I would still personally stick to the previous method shown in this answer using `.Find` and `.Remove`.

```
$array = @('AAD', 'AD')
for ($i = $form.Controls.Count - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
    $control = $Form.Controls[$i]
    if ($control.Name -in $array) {
        $Form.Controls.RemoveByKey($control.Name) # -> Not needed
        # Disposing the control also removes it from the control collection
        $control.Dispose()
    }
}
$form.Controls.Count # 0
```

Comment: The reason why half of the Controls remain is that removing elements in a `foreach` loop modifies the collection you're iterating over. A backwards `for` loop is one of the common counter-measures -- In general, you should dispose of the Controls that are not need anymore instead of removing them. `Controls.Remove()` doesn't dispose anything (this behavior is somewhat different in .NET 5+, though).

Comment: @Jimi that explains the issue and the reverse `for` also solves the problem. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: You're welcome :) As a note, since you are disposing the Controls, calling `Dispose()` is enough. Disposing of a Control also removes it from the `Controls` collection (implemented in the base code)

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77000328/45375):

- Indeed, the problem is your **unsupported attempt to modify** (`.RemoveByKey()`) **a collection** (`$Form.Controls`) ***while it is being enumerated***.

  - **Normally, an *error* should be reported**: `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`<sup>[1]</sup>
  - The fact that **your pipeline instead *aborts quietly* after the first `.RemoveByKey()` call may be a *bug*** - see [GitHub issue #20181](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20181).
- While there are better solutions - see Santiago's answer - all it takes to make your code work is to enclose `$Form.Controls` in `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), which creates a *static copy* of the collection (as an `[object[]]` array), whose enumeration is then isolated from the modifications of the `$Form.Controls` collection:

  ```bash
  # Note the use of @(...)    
  @($Form.Controls) | where { $array -contains $_.Name } | foreach { $Form.Controls.RemoveByKey($_.Name) }
  ```

---

<sup>[1] A simple way to provoke this error: `$l = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]] @('one', 'two'); foreach ($e in $l) { $l.Remove($e) }`</sup>